# How to show "factors of $x$" in Math?

Tags: number-theory, factoring

How to show "factors of $x$" in Math? For example, how can I show "$x$ has $n$ factors" in Math?

Comment: Why not just write $x$ has $n$ factors? Any purely logical representation of this fact will probably be more convoluted.

Comment: Math isn't a foreign language.  To say $x$ has $n$ factors the way to do it is to write... "$x$ has $n$ factors".  That's math.  If you have to define it.  $d$ is a factor of $x$ means $d\in \mathbb N$ and $\frac xd \in \mathbb Z$ so the set of factors of $x$ would be $D=\{d\in \mathbb N|\frac xd \in \mathbb Z\}$ and to say a set has $n$ elements is $|D| = |\{d\in \mathbb N|\frac xd \in \mathbb Z\}|=n$ but... why?.... just say "$x$ has $n$ factors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in\Bbb N$ the number of positive factors of $x$ is the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) of $x$, and is denoted $\sigma_0(x)$, $d(x)$, $\nu(x)$ or $\tau(x)$, so for your purpose you can follow any of those with $=n$.

The set of such factors has no standard symbol, so write it as $\{d\in\Bbb N:d\mid x\}$. If you intend more than just the positive factors, you can adjust these accordingly.